# Mysql JoinInner if not null

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Hi i have following query where it's use joininner statement to get all possible businesses. But when a business is created for first time only 1 category will be updated the rest 2 will remain null

```
public function searchBusinessByCategoryString($str = null, $city=null,$start,$perpage)
    {
$select = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->select();
        $select->from('business as b', array('b.business_name','b.business_url','b.reviews_num','b.cat_id','b.business_id','b.rating','b.business_phone','b.business_add1','b.business_add2','b.x','b.y','b.photo_url'))
               ->joinInner('business_category as bc','b.cat_id = bc.cat_id',array('bc.cat_name'))
               ->joinInner('business_sub_category as bsc','b.sub_cat_id = bsc.b_sub_cat_id',array('bsc.b_subcat_name','bsc.b_sub_cat_id'))
               ->joinInner('business_sub_category as bsc2','b.sub_cat2_id = bsc2.b_sub_cat_id',array('bsc2.b_subcat_name','bsc2.b_sub_cat_id'))
               ->joinInner('business_sub_category as bsc3','b.sub_cat3_id = bsc3.b_sub_cat_id',array('bsc3.b_subcat_name','bsc3.b_sub_cat_id'))
               ->where("bsc.b_subcat_name like '".$str."%'")
                   ->orWhere("bsc.b_subcat_name like '%".$str."'")                   
                   ->orWhere("bsc.b_subcat_name= '".$str."'")
                   ->orWhere("bsc2.b_subcat_name like '%".$str."'")                   
                   ->orWhere("bsc2.b_subcat_name = '".$str."'")
                   ->orWhere("bsc2.b_subcat_name like '".$str."%'")
                   ->orWhere("bsc3.b_subcat_name like '%".$str."'")                   
                   ->orWhere("bsc3.b_subcat_name = '".$str."'")
                   ->orWhere("bsc3.b_subcat_name like '".$str."%'"); 
$result = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
        return $result;
    }
```

Now the issues is how can i not doing joininner query if the rest 2 categories are null? My above statement return empty result event though there is businesses with one category.

Comment: You just have to complete your join condition. Use the initial condition `b.sub_cat_id = bsc.b_sub_cat_id` and append 2 other (` AND bsc.cat2 IS NOT NULL AND bsc.cat3 IS NOT NULL`)

Comment: so where am i add it? on a 2nd joininner query?

Comment: use `leftJoin` instead of `innerJoin` where the joined table can contain NULL value. `INNER JOIN` will join table, using the condition and will not keep lines when a null value is found on the joined table. `LEFT JOIN` will allow you to keep this line.

Answer (score 0):

use `leftJoin` instead of `innerJoin` where the joined table can contain NULL value. `INNER JOIN` will join table, using the condition and will not keep lines when a null value is found on the joined table. `LEFT JOIN` will allow you to keep this line